# SQL second column dependancy on first column values

Tags: sql

I have tabel with two columns

Now if I insert or update column1 with value 0, column2 should not accept any value and should be null

Is their any way to add this constraint

Comment: That depends on DBMS. What DB server do you use?

Comment: I will be implementing it in SQL 2008 and Oracle as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Creating table, you can add the `CHECK` constraint in following way:

```
CREATE TABLE tableDemo (
   column1  int, 
   column2  varchar(50),
   CONSTRAINT CK_column1_column2 CHECK ((column1 = 0 AND column2 IS NULL) OR column1 != 0)
)
```

Check out the **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44cea)**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, you could look at using a [CHECK Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Have a look at the following example

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(
        column_1 INT,
        column_2 VARCHAR(250)
)

ALTER TABLE #Table
ADD CONSTRAINT chkRow CHECK ((column_1 = 0 AND column_2 IS NULL) OR column_1 != 0)

INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 0, NULL
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 0, 'TEST'


INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 1, 'TEST'


UPDATE #Table
SET     column_1 = 0
WHERE   column_1 = 1

SELECT  *
FROM    #Table

DROP TABLE #Table
```

Comment: Thanks for your help 
can I also have somthing like if I fire
INSERT INTO #Table SELECT 0, 'TEST'
a row with 0 in column 1 and Null in column 2 should get inserted.